# OpenCV - How to add a vale to all the pixels in a part of an image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to add a constant value to a rectangular part of a grayscale image.

This is what I have tried:

```c
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cv::Mat src = imread("img.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat temp;

    temp = src(Range(10, 150), Range(10, 210));
    temp.setTo(50);

    imshow("src", src);

    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this makes the area all black (`Scalar(50)`). I wanted to add `50` to all the pixels in that range. Is that possible without using loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `operator+=` for submatrix:

```
temp += 50;
```

[here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions) you have listed matrix expressions. One of them is `A+s` where `A` is your `temp` submatrix and `s` is scalar - 50.